# Opencv trace lines from dotted image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing

I have following image: named 'Normalised.png'. I am trying to draw solid lines from dotted lines.

I have tried approaches like hough line transform:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Normalised.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg',img)
```

But it appears that the code fails on 'edges' as no 'edges' are detected.

Input image

[image: first]

Expected Output Image

[image]

How do I achieve this output?

Comment: Have you given [Eroding and Dilating](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) a try?

Comment: @RickM. yes I have tried those. Also, tried blackout,opening and tophat. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html?highlight=erode .  But they don't give expected result

Comment: Improve the quality of the scan. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [HoughLinesP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) works for straight lines. However, you can detect *curves* by using **cv2.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC** as follows:

```
img = cv.imread("Dilate.png")

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray, 150, 200, apertureSize=3)
cv.imwrite("Canny.png", edges)
element = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3), (-1, -1))
dilated = cv.dilate(edges, element)
cv.imwrite("Eroded.png", dilated)

minLineLength = 200
maxLineGap = 5

lines = cv.HoughLinesP(dilated, cv.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, np.pi/180, 150, minLineLength, 
                       maxLineGap)

for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
        pts = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], np.int32)
        cv.polylines(img, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0))

cv.imwrite('dilate_final.png', img)
```

Note how the lines are being drawn.

Result is not exactly what you want but close and requires you to tune the parameters which I will leave for you. Hope it helps!

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

A possible scheme (though the whole task seems desperate):

- choose a small number of directions (say 5) uniformly spread;
- for every direction,

  - smooth in that direction (f.i. with a very elongated Gaussian) or
  - erode in that direction (with a linear structuring element), or both, to better connect the dots,
  - binarize with threshold such that the dots come in contact,
  - apply morphological thickening to get thin black lines.
- combine all maps so obtained (max operation),
- cleanup.